# Exactness Properties of Schur Functors

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

The title says it all: What are the exactness properties of Schur Functors?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be specific what do you mean by Schur functor. I presume you are saying the Schur functor related to Schur algebra $S(n,r)$ and symmetric  group algebra $F\Sigma_r$, or any similar system such as the functor arising from quasi-hereditary cover of an algebra.  In that case, $F\Sigma_r = e S(n,r) e$ for some idempotent $e$ and the Schur functor is given by $e(-)$.  Well, then exactness follows since $e(-) = \mathrm{Hom}_{S(n,r)} (S(n,r)e, - )$, which is an exact functor.